# Inline style does not givnig it's effect

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, dtd

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<head>
<title>New Page</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type='text' id='Textbox1' name='Textbox' value='Test' maxlength=20  style='left:194; top:43; width:100; height:32; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:14; color:#000000; text-align:left; letter-spacing:0; line-height:0; position:absolute; padding:0; margin:0;   ' />
<button  id='4df60b2d1cf696913aec0377' id='Button1' name='Button' style='left:193.5; top:237.5; width:100; height:32; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:14; color:#000000; text-align:center; letter-spacing:0; line-height:0; position:absolute; padding:0; margin:0; '>Submit</button>
<a name='Anchor' id='Anchor1'href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank' style='left:42.5; top:38.5; width:100; height:32; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:14; color:#000000; text-align:left; letter-spacing:0; line-height:0; position:absolute; padding:0; margin:0; ' >link</a>
<img name='Img' id='Img1' src='i4.jpg' alt='Image not Display' style='left:79.5; top:195.5; width:100; height:32; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; font-size:14; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:left; letter-spacing:0; line-height:0; position:absolute; padding:0; margin:0; '></img>
</body>
</html>
```

this HTML code doesn't getting proper in browser in terms of top-left where i'm making mistakes

Comment: all these elements are inline elements as opposed to blocks, the will not be affected by left, top properties by default. consider using css in the head or externally you will have more options

Comment: to properly use absolute positioning, you need a relative. set the body to position relative. and please don't use inline for that

Comment: I'd suggest you to start using things other than inline styling. You seem to have a lot of styling to do, and it'd be better if you use a external stylesheet, or define tnternally, but not inline.

Comment: @lbu @Balanivash: ok..i will do it externally thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put `px` after non-zero numeric values for it to work.

example: `height: 100px;`

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to forget such things :D